# OSX: Running a shell script?

Tags: xml, macos, shell

I'm new to shell scripts, but I'm trying to run the following script, to download all the .png files from an xml.

Is this the correct way?

```
bash myScript.sh
```

Inside my script I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL='https://theurlwiththexml.com'
i=0
for u in $(curl -s "$URL" |
           grep png | 
           sed -E 's/.*<ImageStuff>(.+)<\/ImageStuff>/\1/'); do
    curl -s "$u" -o $i.png
    (( i++ ))
done
```

The xml on the page looks the following way:

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://url1.com">
  <Name>imagesToUse</Name>
<Prefix/>
<Marker/>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
<Contents>
  <ImageStuff>imagetodownload.png</ImageStuff>
  <Size>17293</Size>
</Contents>
```

Comment: The correct way to what?  Run the script?  Try it and find out.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, but what I meant was "is this the correct way to run a script and pull in the images". Because when I run it, it doesn't report any errors but I don't see any activity beyond that.

Comment: You'd have to concatenate the site URL with the image URL, at least.

Comment: @trojanfoe is that not what s/. is doing?

Comment: Have you tried some debbuging ? For instance, check with `echo $i` and `echo $u` inside your for loop to see if you enter the loop and what is being processed. I tested you script on my computer after replacing `curl` by dummy functions, and it behaves just fine. Is the value between `<ImageStuff>` just a file name or a full URL ? If it is just a file name, there will be an error witch the way you invoke curl

Comment: ohhhh yeah it's just a file name without any slash in front of it

Comment: run your script with `bash -x myscript.sh` and you will see exactly what happens.